# How to run image and Video in async task

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, imageview, android-videoview

I have to run all images and video view in a local folder in async task. I have retrieved all files from a folder. Based on File Type i enable the Visibility of `ImageView` and `VideoView`.

I'm stuck at this point where i have to loop this continuously and keep playing all image and video in async until app is closed. Little guidance would be helpfull.

My existing code

```
private void SetDirectory()
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            m_FolderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

            File txtDirectory = new File(m_FolderPath + "/TestPlayer/");
            // Create a File object for the parent directory
            boolean IsSuccess = false;
            if(!txtDirectory.exists())
            {
                IsSuccess = txtDirectory.mkdir();
            }
            if(IsSuccess == true)
            {
                Log.d("Folder Created" , "Success");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("Folder not Created" , "Not Created");
            }

            List<File> files = loadImageFromStorage(txtDirectory.toString());

            if(files.size() > 0)
            {
                for(int nCount = 0; nCount < files.size() ; nCount ++)
                {
                    String FileName = files.get(nCount).toString();
                    m_CurrentMediaFilePath = FileName;
                    String FileExtension = FileName.substring(FileName.lastIndexOf("."));

                    if(FileExtension.equalsIgnoreCase(".jpg") || FileExtension.equalsIgnoreCase(".png"))
                    {
                        m_VideoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        m_ImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        File imgFile = new File(FileName);
                        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        m_ImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                        m_ImageView.bringToFront();
                        try
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {}
                    }
                    else if(FileExtension.equalsIgnoreCase(".mp4"))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            m_VideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            m_VideoView.bringToFront();
                            //m_ImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            m_VideoView.setVideoPath(FileName);
                            m_VideoView.start();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Log.d("N", ex.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });
}


public class MediaPlayer extends AsyncTask<String,Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values)
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        SetDirectory();
        return "Completed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(5000);` on uiThread will make this app freeze, then it will set up next image but still it will be freezing, after last image is loaded the freeze will end and the UI will be updated, so you will se only last image. 

You have to do it with Handler (created on uithread) and postDelayed, which will posting Runnables wich will show next images, and posting delayed next Runnables to show next images until it is last image.

Comment: Sorry for the Delay.. Is it possible i continuously run this process as it gets over. Once all files are done i can start the process all over again.. I'm comfortable with c# and in c# there is windows media player. we can create a playlist with all image and video. and play all over again. I'm not sure how this can be done in Android.. Is there a way for it..??

Comment: I would start with `Timer`, it allows you to schedule some action, lets say every 5s, and cancel it if needed. Then in this action I would write a method `showCurrentMedia`, which would get currentIndex and show media related to this index and increment this currentIndex (of course if this index is equals to size of your list you have to reset it to zero value to start from beginning)

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Answer (score 1):

another way to do this is something like that:

```
 void showFilesOnUiThread(final List<File> files) {
      new Thread(new Runnable {

          public void run() { 
              for(File file : files) {
                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {  
                          showFile(file);
                      } 
                  });
                  Thread.sleep(5000);
              }
          }
     }).start();
 }
```

of course implementing `showFile` is up to you